# A database operation failed while processing the request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a ASP.Net Core WebApplication in Visual Studio

When I create useraccount in WebApplication I see this error:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "aspnet-webcoredotnet-1f559b4b-ed39-461c-8a18-ed12bbd18a8c" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-UD6R9C4\MohammadDaliri'.

This is my connection string in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=aspnet-webcoredotnet-1f559b4b-ed39-461c-8a18-ed12bbd18a8c;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As the error message says, the windows login `DESKTOP-UD6R9C4\MohammadDaliri` does not have access to your database. Open up your database and give that windows user access.

Comment: thaknks,How can i windows user access in my database.
my database is Sql Server 2012

Comment: I'm curious - what stops you googling this very basic exercise? https://serverfault.com/questions/262199/giving-a-user-database-permissions-in-sql-server-management-studio. Please try something..... anything and then ask a specific question